# Is it possible to set textalign left but placeholder right in TextInput in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to set **textalign** left but **placeholder** right in **TextInput** in ***react-native***

I use sth like this but not work :

```
 <TextInput style={this.state.userName!='' ? styles.defaultText : [styles.defaultText,{textAlign:'left'}]} placeholder='...' autoCapitalize='none' 
            onChangeText={(txt) => this.setState({txtUserName : txt}) }
            value={this.state.txtUserName}></TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the below gives that what you want. I think if you review your state management, your problem will be solved or you can use state like this;

```
const placeHolder = "...";

class Second extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {txtUserName: placeHolder}
}

render() {
    return 
        <TextInput
            style={this.state.txtUserName === placeHolder ? {color:"#000000", textAlign:"right"}:{color:"#a10c93", textAlign:"left"}}
            placeholder={placeHolder}
            autoCapitalize='none'
            onChangeText={(txt) => this.setState({txtUserName: txt})}
            value={this.state.txtUserName}>
        </TextInput>
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check if txtUserName is empty or not. If it is an empty set placeholder text style otherwise set input text style.

Please check below code.

```
<TextInput style={this.state.txtUserName!=='' ? 
            [styles.defaultText,{textAlign:'right'}] :  
            [styles.defaultText,{textAlign:'left'}]} 
            placeholder='...' 
            autoCapitalize='none' 
            onChangeText={(txt) => this.setState({txtUserName : txt}) }
            value={this.state.txtUserName}>
</TextInput>
```

Comment: It has delay,Is it natural?